# ISO 8583 Field 22

Tags: iso8583, openiso8583.net

I'm trying to build an parser to deserialze into object. Socket will send byte into parser. For the length of field 22 POS Entry Mode will N3 and byte will be always 2 digit. How to get the value for this field ?

Answer (score 0):

You read the ASCII value of this field, and convert it into an integer. 
if it says N3 that means they are three digits numeric field, so if the value say 51, you cast it to 051 and send the ASCII equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Field 22 is pos entry mode. It's 3 digit numeric value. If format is BCD then 2 bytes contains 4 digits[ 0 (padded) + 3 digit POS entry mode). If format is ascci then it is 3 byte.